# How to make lava flow faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im making a death run map and I have an area where a lava wave comes and tries to outrun the players. Example:

. So how do you make the lava appear and then disappear so fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a custom map, they probably didn't use the normal lava flow at all, but rather executed many `setblock` commands in a row to place flowing lava. Later, they place air again to remove it.

The syntax is:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> lava[level=<height>]
```

What you have to do is to plan out the sequence, get all the x, y and z coordinates and the lava heights for that spots and put it all into rows of command blocks that have a small delay between them.

That's really complicated. So if you don't need exactly the sequence shown in that video, but rather just fast-flowing lava, you can simply go into the Nether.
(Increasing `randomTickSpeed` no longer works.)

Comment: Does random tick speed affect lava? I haven't seen any evidence of it

Comment: Yes, because of this bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-93468 It was actually fixed for 1.12.2-pre1, but that caused another bug that is harder to fix, so it was for now reverted in 1.12.2.

Answer (score 0):

> Lava travels faster and further in the Nether than in the Overworld.

I daresay, that due to all of the other blocks in the game (Nether Brick, Netherrack, and Magma blocks, etc.) that this was constructed in the Nether.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lava#Flow)

Comment: When they look up in the video, you can see that they are in the Overworld.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to answer from @Fabian:

You can indeed use `setblock` to set a certain block to lava, but I would recommend using the fill command, because
- You can set multiple blocks at once
- You can use a replace option to only replace blocks of a certain type, in your case that would be air.

As an extra, If your death run map goes in only one direction, you could summon an invisible armor stand at the start location and execute the fill command relative to its position. After that, you can move it one block forward and repeat the command. The command would look like this:

```
fill X Y Z X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:lava 0 replace minecraft:air
```

To move the armor stand:

```
teleport X Y Z
```

where X, Y and Z are coordinates relative to the armor stand.

To replace all the lava with air:

```
fill X Y Z X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:lava
```

If you really want to go crazy, you could use structure blocks that contain the lava configuration and fill each row using that structure block, but I have not enough experience to fabricate any commands for that on the fly.

Comment: fill wouldn't work to create exactly the shape in the video, because it had diagonal/rounded edges.